# TypeScript: Generics check for enum type

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

There is an enum for process. They have different steps, which are also represented as enums as shown below.

```js
enum Process {
  Simple = "simple",
  Advanced = "advanced"
}

enum SimpleStep {
  A = "A",
  B = "B"
}

enum AdvancedStep {
  A = "A",
  B = "B",
  C = "C"
}
```

With the following statements, I created an array of steps.

```js
const SIMPLE_STEPS = Object.keys(SimpleStep).map(
  (k: string) => SimpleStep[k]
);

const ADVANCED_STEPS = Object.keys(AdvancedStep).map(
  k => AdvancedStep[k]
);

const ALL_STEPS = {
  [Process.Simple]: SIMPLE_STEPS,
  [Process.Advanced]: ADVANCED_STEPS
};
```

I wrote the following function to get the step number.

```js
// ???: Check if S is a step of Process
const getStepNumber = <P extends Process, S>(process: P, step: S) => {
  return ALL_STEPS[process].indexOf(step) + 1;
};

// returns 2, which is correct
console.log('step number of B', getStepNumber(Process.Advanced, AdvancedStep.B)); 

// returns 0. Is it possible to prevent at compile-time?
console.log('step number of C', getStepNumber(Process.Simple, AdvancedStep.C));
```

As you can see in the code example, is it possible to prevent calling the function with wrong step during compile-time using generics?

Here is the playground, if you wish to try out the whole example: [TS Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYOwrgtgBACgTgewMbAM6qgbwFBSgZQEsIAHAG2CgF4oAiVY84WgGlygEEATANwEMQKLtTp9eAobWwBfbNlCQCjCvgAuwElnYcRtDq3YAhXYamzsSBCFSqCASQCyMADIBRAPr4AKq5j4RAPIARgBWwEiqAHQA1sAAnqgAFESkKuokAJSREHwkieyJ0QBcUDZwhCAA5hnUAHxKqcBqGgDa0QC62BkA3HIK0Nz8gsBczZo4eDo0egZ4xtOmbHgAwrrLZnKW1rYcACIAahwAcsuuu54+foGh4VGxCYmDEiNjWTl57NF1nOLDo+ltTo9TZWGycZzOC6+fw0CZQFrwZBoVCRFJMdolfCOFwebzQpbwxEodCRJ5-DGcA7HU7nPF+GS9Cyg2yVYCqMZHSBBYBwEQAHhgUGAAA91CAuBgiciWARaokSIhiagSjAZTYNJialR6nC4GywHAQODIXT8C0FUj0O1IhUuCKAgAzRLqzJQADUUAAjL1pIytqgEBRImQEJVEgByF1QcAQbm8hAOqCGcMy1ns9Kc2M8xJSklkoQy-MvdKRQwZYH+wPAYOhiNRmNxqAJqDLFNQNMcrnZ3MotEUQu-IRjSLLcuMuTYIA)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to introduce a conditional type that will allow you to infer the require step enum (i.e. `SimpleStep` or `AdvancedStep`) based on the `Process` supplied to the function. This could be done as follows:

```
type StepFromProcess<P extends Process> =
    P extends Process.Simple ? SimpleStep : AdvancedStep
```

Then you could change your function to use that type:

```
const getStepNumber = <P extends Process>(process: P, step: StepFromProcess<P>) => ...
```

The compiler will now prevent you making this (invalid) call:

```
console.log('step number of C', getStepNumber(Process.Simple, AdvancedStep.C));
```

Comment: Wow, that's really cool. Thanks. If there are more than 2 processes, is there switch-case like typing? Or should it be done with ternary conditional expression?

Comment: No, I don't believe there is a switch-case. You need to use nested ternary operators. You can see an example [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#conditional-types) in the TypeScript docs (look at their `TypeName` example there).